# Generate "n" random numbers between a and b to reach desired average in m rows

Tags: vba, excel, random, average

Suppose in column `Z` with 200 rows, are my optimal averages.

Now I want a macro that generates `n` random integers between `a` and `b` inclusive (`n <= 20`) so that difference between the average of numbers generated with optimal average is in `(-0.15,+0.15)`.

Example:

```
Z1:optimal average1=5.5
Z2:optimal average2=5.3

Z200:optimal average200=6.3
n=8
a=1; b=10
numbers of generated:
A1:H1)5-9-4-3-7-4-9-3
A2:H2)10-7-3-2-5-4-3-9
.
.
.
A200:H200)4-8-9-6-6-6-10-2
```

Comment: Can you add the code you have tried and indicate where you are having problems with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zonzt.jpg)

The difference between two means is not within range (0.15+, 0.15-)

Comment: Logically this is more of a comment than an answer, but since you can't post images in a comment I understand the motivation. Perhaps you should later delete this. In any event -- your screenshot suggests that you didn't use the function in an [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7D94A64E-3FF3-4686-9372-ECFD5CAA57C7). Note how in my screen shot I had `{=RandIntVect(8,1,10,I2,0.15)}` with the surrounding braces, but the `{,}` are lacking in your screenshot.

Comment: Also: note that those target means above 8 are over 2.5 standard deviations from the expected sample mean of 5.5. For these values, `maxTries = 1000` misses without a hit will sometimes happen (around 5% of the time). If this is your intended use case, you should think about increasing `maxTries`, either in the function definition itself or when you call it, e.g. `{=RandIntVect(8,1,10,I2,0.15,10000)}`.

Comment: Thank you so much
But I still did not understand
I do all steps  but still do not know where my problem

Comment: You need to enter *one* array formula in `A2:H2`, not separate formulas for each cell. 1) Select the whole range `A2:H2`. 2) type `=RandIntVect(8,1,10,I2,0.15,10000)` (or whatever you would type given your regional settings). Don't type the `{,}` -- Excel will automatically insert those. and 3)Use `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` to enter the formula as an array formula. In any event -- what if you just use VBA to fill the cells? You don't need to use `RandIntVect` as a worksheet function -- call it from VBA.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hit-or-miss approach (which is often the only viable way to get random numbers which satisfy additional constraints in an unbiased way):

```
Function RandIntVect(n As Long, a As Long, b As Long, mean As Double, tol As Double, Optional maxTries As Long = 1000) As Variant
    'Uses a hit-or-miss approach to generate a vector of n random ints in a,b inclusive whose mean is
    'within the tolerance tol of the given target mean
    'The function raises an error if maxTries misses occur without a hit

    Dim sum As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim lowTarget As Double, highTarget As Double 'targets for *sums*
    Dim vect As Variant

    lowTarget = n * (mean - tol)
    highTarget = n * (mean + tol)

    For i = 1 To maxTries
        ReDim vect(1 To n)
        sum = 0
        j = 0
        Do While j < n And sum + a * (n - j) <= highTarget And sum + b * (n - j) >= lowTarget
            j = j + 1
            vect(j) = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(a, b)
            sum = sum + vect(j)
        Loop
        If j = n And lowTarget <= sum And sum <= highTarget Then
            'Debug.Print i 'uncomment this line to see how many tries required
            RandIntVect = vect
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    'error if we get to here
    RandIntVect = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function
```

This could be used as a [worksheet array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7D94A64E-3FF3-4686-9372-ECFD5CAA57C7). The target means were in column `I` and in `A2:H2` I entered `=RandIntVect(8,1,10,I2,0.15)` (with ctrl+shift+enter as an array formula) and then copied down:

[image]

Note that array formulas are volatile, so these numbers would be recalculated every time the worksheet is.  You could use the function in VBA to place the numbers directly in the ranges rather than using the function as a worksheet formula. Something like:

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 3
        Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + 1, 8)).Value = RandIntVect(8, 1, 10, Cells(i + 1, 9).Value, 0.15)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: The difference between two means is not within range (+0.15, -0.15)

Comment: @alirezataghizadeh The formula works properly when entered as an *array formula*. It can be confusing since Excel lets you enter the formula as a non-array formula which works in an unexpected way.