# How to create numbers with normal distribution with set of distinct numbers in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

As we know, formula of `NORMINV(rand();mean;Stdev)` generates numbers with normal distribution between a mean and standard deviation randomly.

I have 17 numbers and want to create a set of 400 random number with this, as their distribution be normal. But `NORMINV()` fuction generates numbers other than my numbers.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NP3rm.jpg)

Comment: You mean you want to generate 400 numbers only using the ones in your list of 17? If so, use RND to generate a random number between 1 and 17.

Comment: For example, in my screenshot, I created 27 randomly random numbers that have  normal distribution but only two numbers are between my optimal numbers

Comment: Your question seems to be "how to create numbers with a normal distribution while having them satisfy conditions which force them to be non-normal?" Please clarify what you are trying to do. For example -- what are the "optimal numbers" you refer to in your comment but not your question? Also, how are the 400 numbers that you are trying to generate supposed to be related to the 17 numbers that you start with?

Comment: I'll explain more clearly
I want to create "N" integer random number between 1 to 5 and get average of them.
First I use of NORMINV(rand();mean;stdvp) (mean is between 1-5 ) to get optimal average and then create random numbers with RandIntVect()  

Now I have "M" averages that is result of numbers created between 1 to 5
But distribution of "M" my averages is not normal.
In other words
I want to create "N" integer number between 1 to 5 in M row so that averages created in "M" row have normal distribution

Comment: Then probably your sample is too small?

Comment: My sample is at least 400

Comment: If you are referring to the function `RandIntVec()` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52026924/4996248), note that that function returns something which can't be conceptualized as a random sample drawn from some distribution (which is a collection of *independent* identically distributed random numbers). That function generated sets of numbers which were chosen to satisfy a constraint, and that constraint induces a dependence between the numbers. There is no reason to expect that the central limit theorem should apply to its output.

Comment: I described steps are done in my new screenshot

Answer (score -2):

New functions is available to generate random number between your lower and upper limits:
    =randbetween(1,99)

Comment: How does this answer a question about how to generate *normal* random numbers? `randbetween()` returns uniformly distributed numbers. This seems more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: Apologies John Coleman, I appear to have misunderstood the original poster and provided insufficient expansion to my comment/answer.  The RandBetween I would have expected to be able to use this as a basis for the outcome with the OP using their own itnerpretation rather than the full blown line for line explanation.  Apologies if you felt this insufficient